# how to break or continue a process block with pipeline input

Tags: powershell

When I run this command, if it gets an error in a try/catch block, it goes to the catch block and then I'd like to do something like issue a continue command so that I can put other commands under that which don't run in that case. Just check a condition (or catch an error) and then exit the process block and let another instance of the process block run with the next item in the pipeline. But, the continue command does not do that. The entire script just ends at that point. Can anyone tell me how to make this happen?
(begin and end blocks redacted)

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param ( 
    [parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
    [string]$ComputerName,
    [parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
    [pscredential]$Credential,
    [parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
    [string]$IPv4Address,
    [string]$userName,
    [string]$log
)
Process {
    Write-Log $ComputerName -foreground yellow
    try {
        if ($Credential) {
            if (! $IPv4Address) {
                "IP address and credential must be used together. If you provide the credential, we need the IP too."
                continue
            }
            $ComputerName = $IPv4Address
            $CredUser = $Credential.UserName
            $password = $Credential.GetNetworkCredential().password
            $WinNTComputer = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("WinNT://$ComputerName", $CredUser, $password,"secure")
            Remove-Variable CredUser, password
        }
        else {
            $WinNTComputer = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("WinNT://$ComputerName")
        }
    }
    catch {
        Write-Log "failed to connect to remote machine $ComputerName. skipping."
        $_
        continue # go to next computer
    }
    try {$IADsUserObj = $WinNTComputer.psbase.children | Where-Object { $_.psBase.schemaClassName -eq "User" -and $_.psbase.Name -eq $userName }}
    catch {
        Write-Log "failed querying for existing user $userName. skipping this computer."
        $_
        continue # go to next computer
    }
    if ($IADsUserObj) {
        # The indicated user exists. Remove it.
        try { $WinNTComputer.Delete('User', $userName) }
        catch {
            Write-Log "failed to remove user $($IADsUserObj.path). skipping."
            $_
            continue # go to next computer
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: change `continue` for `return`. `return` is the control flow keyword. in pwsh it is used to exit early from a scriptblocks or functions, in addition to used in classes where it is mandatory. also note: [Do not use continue outside of a loop, switch, or trap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_continue?view=powershell-7.3#do-not-use-continue-outside-of-a-loop-switch-or-trap) (same applies for `break`)